# Coldfusion Structinsert is overwriting the orignal inserted values

Tags: struct, coldfusion, cfml

I have the following code.

```
<cfset x = StructNew()>
<cfset y = StructNew()>

<cfset y.name = "1">
<cfset y.id = "2">

<cfset structInsert(x,"item1",y)>

<cfdump var="#x#">
```

This outputs the following, which I expect.

```
struct
item1 struct
      name  1
      id    2
```

Then I add this code to insert another set of data.

```
<cfset y.name = "3">
<cfset y.id = "4">

<cfset structInsert(x,"item2",y)>

<cfdump var="#x#">
```

This outputs the following.

```
struct
item1 struct
      name  3
      id    4
item2 struct
      name  3
      id    4
```

Why did the item1 data change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, structInsert isn't overwriting the values - you are - when you do this:

```
 <cfset y.name = "3">
 <cfset y.id = "4">

 <!--- show values before structInsert --->
 <cfdump var="#x#">
```

(Notice the dump shows the `item1` data has already changed, even *before* calling structureInsert again?)

The reason is that structures are passed [by reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference). Meaning `x.item1` is only a *pointer* to the `y` structure, not an independent copy. So when the code updates the values of `y.name` and `y.id`, those changes are automatically reflected in `x.item1` as well.

If you want the `y` structure to be completely independent, either create a *new* structure first (or use [duplicate()](https://cfdocs.org/duplicate) to make a deep copy).

```
<cfset y = structNew()>
<cfset y.name = "3">
<cfset y.id = "4">
```

Having said that, unless there's a specific reason for using structInsert(), using structure or dot notation is more standard these days:

```
 <cfset x.item1 = y> ... or
 <cfset x["item1"] = y>
```

Also, you could reduce the code a LOT by using the shortcut syntax `{}` for creating and/or populating structures. Here's the entire example in one line:

```
<cfset x = { "item1": {"name": "1", "id": "2"}
        , "item2": {"name": "3", "id": "4"}
       }>
```

... or if you needed to append structures individually, use:

```
<cfset x = {}>
<cfset x["item1"] = {"name": "1", "id": "2"}>
<cfset x["item2"] = {"name": "3", "id": "4"}>
```

Comment: Thank you Ageax. I will take all this into consideration.  I used the Duplicate for now.

Comment: That'll work, but .. unless you really need to duplicate all keys in the structure it's simpler to create a new one. Also, sleeker and shorter to use `{}` than all the separate cfset's IMO :-)

Comment: Pass by Reference vs Pass by Value is always such a fun discussion. :-)